# Garage Band alternative for windows

Tags: audio-recording, audio-quality

Is there any software for windows which can perform live audio modification during recording. I have a samson go usb mic but still records are a bit lacking in terms of the professional audio quality like a hint of a reverb etc.

I know garage band for Mac has ability to have these effects in real time to your audio. Any software for windows or other alternative to have that high bass cool sounding audio for podcasts/screencasts.

Answer (score 2):

One that comes to mind is Presonus Studio One vr3 It is about $50 and is a full featured digital audio workstation. There is also sonar, protools and ableton live but I believe they are all quite a bit more expensive.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I recently switched from GarageBand to **Ableton Live**, partially because Live is known for its smooth realtime performance.  Live is geared for on stage performances so it should do fine with effects you add in realtime.  I've been bitten by GarageBand before because there have been some latencies when recording, switching instruments, etc.

Live is definitely higher end software, but you can pick up the basic package for around $100 (closer to $80 if you get it on sale) for both macOS<sup>[[1]](https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001261150-MacOS-Compatibility)</sup> and Windows<sup>[[2]](https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/209775965-Windows-Compatibility)</sup>.  It's a bit tricky to learn at first but rewarding once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I need for windows.

Comment: @garg10may it is compatible with macOS and Windows.  I added links in my answer.